# Why is "a b c" always printed at the end of this code, despite the actual value of the variables?

Tags: python

Why is "a b c" always printed at the end of this code, despite the actual value of the variables, and how do I make it print the actual values?

```
a = "a"
b = "b"
c = "c"

def GiveValueTo(variable):
    while True:
        try:
            variable = float(input("\nEnter a value for " + str(variable) + ":\n"))
            break
        except:
            print(variable, "must be a real number")

GiveValueTo(a)
GiveValueTo(b)  
GiveValueTo(c)

print(a, b, c)
```

Comment: look up python scoping

Comment: Assigning to `variable` inside the function does NOT update the value of the outer parameter.  That's not how Python parameters work.

Comment: Should be rewritten as `a = GiveValueTo()` with a `return variable` in `GiveValueTo`.

Comment: ``a`` remains ``"a"`` and you never assign another value to ``a``. Changing ``variable`` has absolutely no impact on ``a``. You send a photo of your car to a friend and that friend paints that photo green. Is your car green now? No. Same here.

Comment: If the function actually worked the way you believe it does - then what do you think would happen if you called it as `GiveValueTo("d")` or `GiveValueTo(a + b)`?  Both of those are perfectly valid ways of calling a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of call, like fortran subroutines, which modify the function arguments is not how things are done in python.

When you pass a variable to a function, it becomes an argument which becomes local to the function when the function is called, and cease to exist when the function terminates.

It looks like you mostly want a function that sets a variable as a value, which you can do with `return`.

```py
def GiveValueTo(var_name):
    while True:
        try:
            val = float(input("\nEnter a value for " + var_name + ":\n"))
            return val
        except:
            print(var_name, "must be a real number")

a = GiveValueTo("a")  # pass the name you want and get the value from input
b = GiveValueTo("b")  
c = GiveValueTo("c")

print(a, b, c)
```

See [this section of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#id9)

> What are the rules for local and global variables in Python?
>
> In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly declared as global.
>
> Though a bit surprising at first, a moment’s consideration explains this. On one hand, requiring global for assigned variables provides a bar against unintended side-effects. On the other hand, if global was required for all global references, you’d be using global all the time. You’d have to declare as global every reference to a built-in function or to a component of an imported module. This clutter would defeat the usefulness of the global declaration for identifying side-effects.

Comment: Is it possible to use "global" somehow to make it work?

Comment: I don't see how it would be possible because `global` needs to know which variable to make global, and I don't see how you could tell it from the function arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Well nowhere in GiveValueTo are you actually setting the value of a,b, or c. You are simply setting what the value of "variable" is which is simply a variable that only exists within the scope of the function GiveValueTo. Once that method terminates, "variable" no longer exists, a, b,c have never been reassigned and they are going to print the initial values set at the first three lines.

This is indeed a problem of scope in that when you pass in the variables a, b, c you aren't passing in the space in memory where those variables live, but instead simply their values. So "variable" starts as "b" if you pass "b" in, but then when you set its value in your try block, you aren't changing the original variable b, you are just changing a variable that only exists in the function from "b" to whatever the user input sets it to.